# Can't set PageLoad of ChromeDriver instance

Tags: .net, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, cross-browser

long time lurker here, now it's time for my first real post.
I am currently developing a cross browser test for our application with Selenium in .NET.

Following http://www.guru99.com/cross-browser-testing-using-selenium.html, I implemented this:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSetup()
{
    public static IWebDriver driver;
    ...

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        if(browserToTest.Equals("Firefox"))
        {
              driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browserToTest.Equals("Chrome"))
        {
              driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);

        // navigate to url, login, etc. pp
    }
}
```

In the "Firefox" case, everything works great. The "Chrome" case - in contrary to the tutorial - gives me this error:

**OneTimeSetUp: System.NotImplementedException : Driver instance must comply with the W3C specification to support getting timeout values.**

Im using:

- Firefox v54.0
- Chrome v59.0.3071.115
- Selenium.WebDriver v3.4.0
- Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver v0.17.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v2.30.0.1

Can I set ImplicitWait and PageLoad for chrome, or is this only implemented for firefox?

Comment: I'm curious why don't you get error messages when building the code. `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);` It is Timeouts, not TimeOuts.

Comment: I didn't copy the src 1:1, that's just a stupid typo :) corrected it

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. I think it is a compatibility issue. Could you cleanup the chromedriver from `/bin` uninstall and then reinstall it?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I didn't have time yet to further develop our tests. Anyway, it actually was some sort of compatibility issue. After checking out the project on my fresh new workstation, it worked straight away.

Comment: You should check this repo: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager to avoid these kind of problems. It's an automated web driver managers that gets the correct drivers and versions for you

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,timeunit.seconds)
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,timeunit.seconds)
```

And this is with selenium 3

Answer (score 0):

i used this code which worked for me in both chrome and firefox. PageObject is my class and waitPageToLoad is my method.

```
public class PageObject {
    protected Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected WebDriverWait wait;

  public WebDriver getDriver() {
    log.debug("obtaining the driver object for current thread");
    return driver;
} 
 public WebDriverWait getWait() {
    log.debug("obtaining the wait object for current thread");
    return wait;
}
 public void initialise(Object obj) {
    PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), obj);
}

 public PageObject waitPageToLoad() {
        domLoaded();
        jqueryLoaded();
        return this;
    }

 public void domLoaded() {
        log.debug("checking that the DOM is loaded");
        final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        Boolean domReady = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");

        if (!domReady) {
            getWait().until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    return (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
                }
            });
        }
    }

  private void jqueryLoaded() {
        log.debug("checking that any JQuery operations complete");
        final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();

        if ((Boolean) js.executeScript("return typeof jQuery != 'undefined'")) {
            boolean jqueryReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");

            if (!jqueryReady) {
                getWait().until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return window.jQuery.active === 0");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```